# How to a make a model in sequelize to has a many to many relation-ship with the same model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table in the database called category, that has an Id, name, image. I want to add that category may also has category, for example lets assume I have a category named women clothes, men clothes, and clothes. I want to add the category women clothes and the men clothes to the category clothes, (these 3 are categories). so how can we implement like this in Sequelize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need a junction table, a Sequelize model for it and of course two associations `belongsToMany`:

```js
// let's assume you already have CategoryLink model:
Category.belongsToMany(Category, { through: CategoryLink, foreignKey: 'parentCategoryId', otherKey: 'subCategoryId', as: 'subCategories' });
Category.belongsToMany(Category, { through: CategoryLink, foreignKey: 'subCategoryId', otherKey: 'parentCategoryId', as: 'parentCategories' });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but How should I design the CategoryLink table, I mean what attributes should I add into it ?

Comment: It's enough to have a PK field and these two fields `parentCategoryId` and `subCategoryId` that should be foreign key columns to Category's PK field.